# jquery slideUp to a minimum height

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slideup

I'm using jQuery's resizable().
I want to minimize the resizable() div, using slideUp\Down to some minimum height.

Please advice,
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464899/is-it-possible-to-slidetoggle-a-div-with-easing-and-set-a-min-height

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, set the div to have a `min-height`, and jQuery will respect that height when being resized.