# Is it possible to slideToggle a div with Easing and set a min-height?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slidetoggle, css

I have a div of which collapse and expands using slideToggle and easing.

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('div').slideToggle('2000', "easeOutBounce");
});
```

I want it when it slide's Up to have a minimum height so that there always a small visible content of it.

**So when it's slide down has `height:(div height)` and on `slideUp, height:10px;`**

Note that the div could have any amount of height so that's why I am not using animation.

Comment: jQuery has a `.fadeTo`. It would be nice if it had a native `.slideTo`.

Comment: you mean SlideFadeToggle

Comment: @jQuerybeast: no, I think he means `.slideTo(heightToSlideElementTo)` =) But hey, `slideFadeToggle()` could be awesome too..! =D

Comment: slideFadeToggle would be really awesome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I could come up with is the following:

```
var toggleMinHeight = 30,
    duration = 2000,
    easing = 'swing';
$('.toggles').each(
    function(){
        $(this).attr('data-height',$(this).height());
    }).click(
    function(){
        var curH = $(this).height();
        if ($(this).is(':animated')){
            return false;
        }
        else if (curH == $(this).attr('data-height')) {
            $(this).animate(
                {
                    'height' : toggleMinHeight
                }, duration, easing);
        }
        else if (curH == toggleMinHeight){
            $(this).animate(
                {
                    'height' : $(this).attr('data-height')
                }, duration, easing);
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/STzmB/1/).

This demo has some issues, however:

- No easing functionality beyond that specified by the basic jQuery library (giving access to 'swing' and 'linear'), this could be improved by including jQuery UI, however.
- It could almost certainly be made into a plug-in, to be somewhat less icky to look at.
- Requires a large, functional but not pretty, `if`/`else if` statement.
- Requires at least one pass of the `each()` to assign the 'default'/'natural' height of the div elements.
- If the `div`s aren't `position: absolute` they shrink down to the baseline of the in-line elements (as they're `display: inline-block`), this may not be a problem if they're `float: left` (or `float: right`, obviously).

Hopefully it's of use, but it's certainly not ideal in its current state.

---

**Edited** to post the plugin-ised version of the above (it retains all the same issues as before):

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.slideTo = function(slideToMin, duration, easing) {

        var slideToMin = slideToMin || 30,
            duration = duration || 500,
            easing = easing || 'linear';
        $(this)
            .attr('data-height', $(this).height())
            .click(
                function() {
                    var curH = $(this).height();
                    if ($(this).is(':animated')) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if (curH == $(this).attr('data-height')) {
                        $(this).animate({
                            'height': slideToMin 
                        }, duration, easing);
                    }
                    else if (curH == slideToMin) {
                        $(this).animate({
                            'height': $(this).attr('data-height')
                        }, duration, easing);
                    }
                });

        return $(this);
    };
})(jQuery);

$('.toggles').slideTo(50,1500,'swing');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/STzmB/2/).

1. slideToMin: this can be *either* a quoted string, such as '3em', '20px', or an unquoted number, such as `30`, and represents the height to which you want the element to slide to. If there are no units supplied then the height is, by default, considered to be in pixels.
2. duration: the number of milliseconds for which the animation lasts.
3. easing: <s>a quoted string defining the type of easing to be used in the animation; without jQuery UI this is either 'linear' or 'swing'. *With* jQuery UI other options may be possible, but this is untested. If unspecified the animation defaults to 'linear.'</s> Because using units in a quoted string causes the final `else if` to return false (obviously, I suppose...sigh), please use only an unquoted numerical argument for this variable (or edit the plug in to properly deal with quoted strings with units...).

A larger issue that I hadn't realised until I posted this, is that the plugin version only allows *one* iteration of the animation. Which I'm confused about, though perhaps it's obvious to someone else?

Okay, it appears to be the evaluation of the height in the `if` statement. Using `3em` caused the final `else if` : `curH == toggleMinHeight` to return false. Presumably due to the presence of the unit (`em`) in that variable. The above guidance has been edited to reflect that the units should *not* be used.

---

References:

- [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).
- [`:animated` selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/).
- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/).
- [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).

Comment: Oh, it really isn't...look at those issues! But thank you; now if someone could explain to me why the plug-in version doesn't work correctly/consistently I'd appreciate it... =/ Anyway! I'm glad to have been of help, thank you for the accept! =D

Comment: I'll go through the plugin deeply afterwards and I will let you know. I'll try and fix the position:absolute too. There should be a way without using that.

Comment: In case you have time you could take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199327/trying-to-load-an-api-and-a-js-file-dynamically It looks that it's gonna be easy for you lol :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not really. When the slide method is called, it gets the style property

```
display: none;
```

However, you may be able to dynamically fix it by using the callback function

```
$('div').slideToggle('2000', "easeOutBounce", function() {
     $('div')[0].style.height="//whatever//"     //You could also use the min-height property
     $('div')[0].style.display="inline";
);
```

What exactly is the problem with animation?

Comment: His function was missing a `}`. I added it in.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you play it tricky;

why dont you have a div above the sliding div that has the same width and color so that it is always displayed and appears as part of the sliding part

Comment: I thought of it but its for blog posts. It a huge turnaround to make that. I thought a tricky way with this would work. Thanks

Comment: I will give another suggestion, checkout the answer below

Comment: You can use the $.append function to add the div that we have discussed with a class with the appropriate height, if you need help in this please post some more code and i will help