# How show a little of DIV text when using jQuery slideToggle?

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I have web page wherein I want to show several user comments.  I want to show the first couple of lines and then (using jQuery) let the user expand to see all of it, and then collapse to take it back down to just the first few lines.

I'm using jQuery slideToggle method just fine however, it collapses it down to nothing displayed at all.  I want to collapse down to (like I said) the first couple of lines (or 50px height or whatever).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: jQuery slideToggle method sets display:none;, so you can not set height in this one. you can try something with setting height in jquery may be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to slideToggle a div with Easing and set a min-height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464899/is-it-possible-to-slidetoggle-a-div-with-easing-and-set-a-min-height)

Answer (score 0):

jquery: `$(".comment:nth-child(n+3)").slideToggle();`

css : `.comment:nth-child(n+3){ display: none;};`.
This is a possible solution to your problem since it will target only the comments that are not the first three children. 
downside is that it will toggle each one of them seperatly.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you can use `readmore.js`

It is easy to use `$('#target').readmore();`

```
<div id="target">Some long text here</div>
```

See more of it here [Readmore.js](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Lightweight-jQuery-Read-More-Link-Plugin-Readmore-js/)

**FIDDLE:** See it in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/64xLqrpq/1/)

Answer (score -1):

```js
var toggleMinHeight = 30,
    duration = 2000,
    easing = 'swing';
$('.toggleDiv').each(
    function(){
        $(this).attr('data-height',$(this).height());
    }).click(
    function(){
        var curH = $(this).height();
        if ($(this).is(':animated')){
            return false;
        }
        else if (curH == $(this).attr('data-height')) {
            $(this).animate(
                {
                    'height' : toggleMinHeight
                }, duration, easing);
        }
        else if (curH == toggleMinHeight){
            $(this).animate(
                {
                    'height' : $(this).attr('data-height')
                }, duration, easing);
        }
    });
```

```css
.toggleDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 0 1%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggleDiv">
    <p>click on text to slide toggle


Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum..</p>
</div>
```